# for a key group record, Replicating values replacing null values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, informatica

Source and target table is same.
1) for col1 in source,  col 2 havs some value and null value then in target, value should be copied to replacing null value field for a particularkey record.

2)for col1 in source, if there is only null value, then in target col 2 should have -1

3) for col1 in source, if any time col1=ABC then in target col2 value must be -2.

So,
a) there are two types of values for col 1 in source: ABC and non-ABC.

b) For a record group col 2 should have value if available or -1 if no value available.

c) For non-ABC records target should have col2=-2

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What will be the mapping flow?
Also, how it can possible in SQl query.

Thanks in Advance.

```
SOURCE  
Col1    col2
  P1    123
  P1    NULL
  P1    NULL
  P2    NULL
  P3    NULL
  P3    456
  P4    NULL
  P4    NULL
  ABC   NULL



TARGET  
 Col1   col2
  P1    123
  P1    123
  P1    123
  P2    -1
  P3    456
  P3    456
  P4    -1
  P4    -1
  ABC   -99
```

Comment: Your rules do not specify where -99 comes from.

Comment: abc= -99 will be hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

You can produce the target you want using analytic functions, based on the rules you describe:

```
select s.col1,
       coalesce(max(col2) over (partition by col1), -1) as col2
from source s;
```

This does not explain how you get `99` for "ABC", but your question doesn't explain that rule.

Comment: Above query does not give any result for record in col1 for ABC.  Means if ABC exists in col1 source then in target value for col2 it shuld come as -2

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. Use the below query in Source Qualifier:

```
select col1, max(col2)
from source
group by col1
```

In an Expression transformation implement your logic. For example:

```
out_col2 := IIF(col1='ABC','-2',
             IIF(ISNULL(col2), -1, col2))
```

Now pass the data through an Update Strategy (with DD_UPDATE) and connect the columns col1 and out_col2 to the target.

**Make sure you have defined col1 as primary key in your target definition.**